# switch key tables in tmux

Tags: tmux

I want tmux to work more like vim, i.e. there's a normal mode and an insert mode.
Tmux has keytables, and supports custom keytables, so I can `bind Escape -T insert` to switch to Normal mode, but what is the command for normal mode? How do I actually *use* a custom keytable? `switch-client -T <mode>` says it will use keytable `<mode>` for the next keypress, but how do I get it to use that one keytable for all keypresses (until one of the keypresses uses the same command to switch modes again)?

Comment: I believe it to be either `prefix` or `root`, as taken from [here](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#bind-key). You might also find some more information from [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/tmux/comments/6920do/til_custom_keytables_with_switchclient_t/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=mweb). Sorry I can't help more; I've just started learning this myself!

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do - provide some examples. How does this differ from what copy mode already does?